# expo-notications: Local Notification Not Triggering BackgroundNotificationTask

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, expo, expo-notifications

I'm new to the react-native and expo, and I'm running into an issue with expo-notifications running background tasks with local notifications.

The `expo-notification` [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#notification-events-listeners) states that the background notification event listener without user interaction only runs tasks using `BackgoundNotificationTask`.  [This is achieved using the `expo-task-manager` library](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#notification-events-listeners).

When implemented, the background task doesn't run when it's a local notification scheduled using the `scheduleNotificationAsync` method.

I've tried using the `handleSuccess` and `handleNotification` callbacks to run code in the background, but neither of these methods are called if the app is in the background.

I'm using the EAS development build to run my app on Android 13.

I'd be open to suggestions on other ways to implement run code in the background when a local notification is received.